# Getting error while integrating "Google Identity Services" in angular13

Tags: google-signin, google-identity

I am working in angular13 and updating the "Google Sign-In JavaScript Platform Library" to "Google Identity Services".

test.component.ts

```
google.accounts.id.initialize({
   client_id: clientId,
   callback: this.handleCredentialResponse
});
google.accounts.id.renderButton(
   document.getElementById("googleBtn"),
   { 
      theme: "outline", 
      size: "large", 
      width: "300px",
      type: "standard",
      shape: "rectangular",
      text: "'Google sign in'",
      logo_alignment: "center"
   }  // customization attributes
);
handleCredentialResponse(response) {
   var base64Url = (response.credential).split('.')[1];
   var base64 = base64Url.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
   var jsonPayload = decodeURIComponent(window.atob(base64).split('').map(function(c) {
       return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
   }).join(''));
   const responsePayload = JSON.parse(jsonPayload);
   let user : any = {
      id : responsePayload.sub,
      name : responsePayload.name,
      email : responsePayload.email,
      photoUrl : responsePayload.picture,
      firstName : responsePayload.given_name,
      lastName : responsePayload.family_name,
      provider : 'GOOGLE'
   }
   this.getUserData(user);
}
getUserData(user: any){
   ....
}
```

getting error: this.getUserData(user) is not a function.

I am unable to access any functions under handleCredentialResponse() function.

Comment: Where is getUserData() defined? Is this executes in a Angular Context or via @script> ?

Comment: @Vega Yes this is in Angular context and getUserData() is defined under .ts file of component.

Comment: Is the above snippet inside the same component? this refers to the scope of the component and this snippet is outside of it (looks like), so this.get... is undefined